# How to read file and returns as list, dictionary

Tags: python

I had this current text file as inventory.txt

```
<br>C01:10,10,5,4</br>    
<br>C02:0,20,10,5</br>      
<br>C03:10,20,10,1</br>
<br>C04:0,0,10,0</br>
<br>C5:1,1,1,1</br>
```

I would like to use python to read my file and using a dictionary and lists to populate the output as below.

```
{'C01':[10, 10, 5, 4], 'C02':[0, 20, 10, 5], 'C03':[10, 20, 10, 1], 'C04':[0, 0, 10, 0], 'C05:[1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

This is my code so far:

```
for line in file:
    item , stock = line.split(":")
   
    a = stock.strip().split(",")
    b = item
    c = stock
    num1, num2, num3, num4 = stock.strip().split(",")
    #print(a)    #print ['10', '10', '5', '4']
    #print(b)    #print C01
    #print(c)    #print 10, 10, 5, 4
storeNumber[item] = [str(num1), str(num2), str(num3), str(num4)]
print(storeWord[item])
```

But this is not producing the desired output.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You're not far off:

```
dx = {
    key: [int(i) for i in value.strip().split(",")]
    for key, value in ((l.split(":")[0], l.split(":")[1]) for l in file)
}
```

All this does is use a dictionary comprehension to assign to each key the split-out list for each line. The internal generator (`((l.split..., ...) for l in file)`) takes each line of the file and turns it into a tuple of the first and second elements of a split on the `:` character. Being a generator, it's not called immediately, only when the dictionary comprehension passes over it.

The dictionary comprehension takes the first value of the tuple (the key) and assigns it as the dictionary key, and then takes the value, splits it on `,`. This naturally produces a list, which can be iterated over to produce ints for each element if desired using a for-comprehension.

```
>>> file = [
... "C01:10,10,5,4",
... "C02:0,20,10,5",
... "C03:10,20,10,1",
... "C04:0,0,10,0"]
>>> dx = {
...         key: [int(i) for i in value.strip().split(",")]
...         for key, value in ((l.split(":")[0], l.split(":")[1]) for l in file)
...     }
>>> dx
{'C01': [10, 10, 5, 4], 'C02': [0, 20, 10, 5], 'C03': [10, 20, 10, 1], 'C04': [0, 0, 10, 0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
storeNumber = dict()
with open("inventory.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        item, stock = line.strip().split(":")
        storeNumber[item] = [int(i) for i in stock.split(",")]
```

Comment: I *think* `i.strip()` isn't needed, since `int("  1  ")` produces the int `1` right?

Comment: @NathanielFord - Spot on! Edited :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a quick loop like so. Note that this assumes your data is all valid and formatted correctly. :

```
f = open('file.txt')

output_dict = {}

for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if len(line) > 0:
        split_line = line.split(':')
        output_dict[split_line[0]] = [int(x) for x in split_line[1].split(',')]
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to the end of the for loop:

`storeNumber.update({b:a})`